# Is it possible to rename a whole variable in C++?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm really new to programming. So bear with me if the question sounds stupid:
If I rename a variable, do I have to rewrite all mentions? Or is there a way to replace all mentions with the new variable name?
I'm writing in C++ in Visual Studio.
Would be awesome if someone could answer my question:)

Right now I'm always replacing all Mentions of the variable, but I've been thinking if this could go faster in any way?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/rename?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most IDEs, including Visual Studio, have built-in refactoring capabilities.

In Visual Studio, you can select the variable and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. You'll get an input box to fill in the new name, and Visual Studio will take care of the rest for you.

Comment: F2 [no longer works](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/f2-rename-no-longer-works/648967) in VS2019.

Comment: @heapunderrun Yikes, you're right. Old habits die hard. Edited and fixed.

Comment: Note that you have to press Ctrl+R _twice_.

Answer (score 2):

Select the variable you want to rename, and go to Edit > Refactor > Rename. This opens the dialog box, and then you can add a new name for the variable VS code automatically update all occurrences of the variable name in your code.

Comment: It's Visual Studio, not VS code :)